# Will upvotes to a question affect the reputation of the question's editor(s)?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

Stack Exchange users automatically gain a +2 reputation boost from editing questions and having their edits accepted. However, I think users should also earn reputation for making edits to answers that earn more upvotes for those answers. If a user edited a relatively weak answer, and therefore caused the answer to earn a lot of upvotes, would the user earn any reputation from the subsequent upvotes to that answer, due to the substantial improvement that they had made to the original answer?

The current editing system leads to a rather interesting problem: if a user made a substantial improvement to a poorly-written answer, then the original poster would gain reputation from the answer that the editor had written. Essentially, the original poster would earn reputation for the editor's work, while the editor would earn next to nothing.

Comment: No, only the original author gains reputation. Users gain +2 rep when suggesting edits because they have not met the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) limit [required for free editing](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: No, edits are only meant to improve the readability and understanding of a post. All the ideas and information should already be there and that's why only the person who posted it gets the reputation. If you're adding so much information to an answer that you feel worthy of receiving reputation, you should be posting your *own* answer, or the post should be community wiki.

Comment: Sometimes I get a feeling why is Rep everything for users. Isn't the primary objective to ask and answer questions, develop a bonding with fellow users of the community.. Participate to enhance one's own knowledge and make the internet a little more better.. What would one do with all the Rep except for the privileges that are unlocked as we progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only the original author gains reputation. Users gain +2 rep when suggesting edits because they have not met the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) limit [required for free editing](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Additionally, if users who edit an answer share the reputation change due to upvotes/downvotes, who's to say what percentage of the reputation should be attributed to each? There's no way to gauge part ownership in this type of system.

Moreover, if a user has a *substantial* amount of information that will help answer a question, and said user *wants* to bask in the vast amounts of reputations - then said user should **post an answer**.

---

**Edit:** One major difference with the above opinion is the *[community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki)* [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki). In community wiki answers, everyone should pitch in to the existing/accepted answer by improving **it**. There is **absolutely no reputation** change involved in upvotes/downvotes of community wiki.

Comment: This leads to a rather interesting problem: if a user made a substantial improvement to a poorly-written answer, then the original poster would gain reputation from the answer that the editor had written. Essentially, one user would be taking the credit for another user's work.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Absolutely, and that's when said user (making the improvement) should consider posting their own independent answer or not. It's really a matter of how *important* rep is to said user.

Comment: @AndersonGreen The real reason behind editing is to *improve* an existing post (whether a question or an answer); however, if the user *knows* they have a considerably better answer (even if it starts on the same grounds as an existing one), they can post a separate answer. The only caveat to that is *community wiki* answers. In community wiki answers, everyone should pitch in to the existing/accepted answer by improving it - but then again, there is no reputation change involved in upvotes/downvotes of community wiki.